# How to make google chart legend appear bottom and vertical?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

The legend on Google charts are appearing vertical when positioned on the right side.

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  'packages': ['corechart']
});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {

  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
    ['Work', 11],
    ['Eat', 2],
    ['Commute', 2],
    ['Watch TV', 2],
    ['Sleep', 7]
  ]);

  var options = {
    title: 'My Daily Activities',
    pieHole: 0.5,
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));

  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="piechart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
```

But, when we position it at the top or bottom, the legends are in single line (horizontal). I tried using CSS to affect that style, but no luck. Need a solution for this. I want to make the legends appear vertical when positioned at the bottom.

I tried alignment: center too. Didn't work!!!

```
legend: 'bottom', alignment: 'center',
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/e4t9s85u/) is the fiddle for you

Comment: its not working, you need to hide legend and build it with html/css by your own outside of the chart

Comment: That can be done. But, there is no other option to just alter something from the chart script itself?